# Where can I get the Android Pokemon go app?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've seen a post about Pokemon go by a friend on Facebook but when I searched on Google play I saw all sorts of apps except for one named Pokemon go which is what I was looking for. Can someone please provide a link? Is this a free our a paid app, and is it just designed so that people burn gasoline to go on their Pokemon hunts (what a waste)?

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo. It days my device is not compatible. Strange. Why????

[image]

Comment: Are you in one of the regions in which the game is officially released? If so, it should definitely show up [on the Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en).

Comment: The device also has to meet the device requirements or else it won't show up on the phone's play store.

Comment: So why is my device not compatible? What is it missing? It has GPS and Wi-Fi already.

Comment: It's probably missing an updated version of Android.

Comment: ...clear your notifications. Please.

Comment: Based on how your status bar looks, you're not using a recent enough android version so you're going to have to update it to anywhere from version 4.4 to 6.0.1

Comment: What's the problem with the notifications?

Comment: Like Kevin said, you're going to need to update your OS to KitKat (4.4.4), which is the most recent version of Android your model of phone supports.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't find it in your play store is most likely because your phone doesn't meet the requirements:

Android 4.4 to Android 6.0.1 (Android N will not supported until the official Android release)
Preferred resolution of 720x1280 pixels (Not optimized for tablet)
Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
GPS and Location Services.
Intel CPUs are not supported

iPhone 5+
iOS 8+
Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
GPS and Location Services.
Jailbroken devices are not supported

[Source](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/03/phone-requirements-for-pokemon-go.html)

Comment: What's the difference between GPS and Location Services? My Android device is rooted. If not Intel, which I thought was ubiquitous, what CPU do I need?

Comment: Just a note that while the specs say "Jailbroken devices are not supported" there have been plenty of people that say jailbroken and rooted devices work fine.

Comment: Yea my android is rooted and it runs just fine on it and didn't have to do anything to make the game work. Your CPU and GPS should be fine, just upgrade your firmware.